# Amount of properties per command/event in event sourcing

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm learning cqrs/event sourcing, and recently I listen some speach and speaker told that you need pass as few parameters to event as possible, in other words to make events tiny as possible. The main reason for that is it's impossible to change events later as it will break the event history, and its easelly to design small events correctly. But what if for example in UI you need fill in for example form with 10 fields to create new aggregate, and same situation can be with updating the aggregate? How to be in such a case? And how to be if business later consider to change something, but we have huge event which updating 10 fields?

Answer (score 1):

The decision is always context-specific and each case deserves its own review of using *thin* events vs *fat* events.

The motivation for using thin domain events is to include just enough information that is required to ensure the state transition.

As for fat events, your projections might require a piece of entity state to avoid using any logic in the projection itself (best practice).

For integration, you'd prefer emitting fat events because you hardly know who will consume your event. Still, the content of the event should convey the information related to the meaning of the event itself.

References:

- [Putting your events on a diet](https://particular.net/blog/putting-your-events-on-a-diet)
- [Patterns for Decoupling in Distributed Systems: Fat Event](https://verraes.net/2019/05/patterns-for-decoupling-distsys-fat-event/)

Answer (score 0):

> recently I listen some speach and speaker told that you need pass as few parameters to event as possible, in other words to make events tiny as possible.

I'm not convinced that holds up.  If you are looking for good ides about designing events, you should review [Greg Young's e-book on versioning](https://leanpub.com/esversioning).

If you are event *sourcing*, then you are primarily concerned with ensuring that your stream of events allows you to recreate the state of your domain model.  The events themselves should be representations of changes that a domain expert will recognize.  If you find yourself trying to invent smaller events just to fit some artificial constraint like "no more than three properties per event" then you are going to end up with data that doesn't really match the way your domain experts think -- which is to say, technical debt.